# Service Call in Dojo2

Tags: dojo, dojo2

I trying to get the data from server and trying to render in UI but while making service call I am getting the below error.

**Calling service API:**

```
const json = request('http://localhost:8080/part/findall').then(response => response.json());
```

**Error:**

```
Task.js:243 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Task.js:243
    at handler (ExtensiblePromise.js:137)
```

I am getting the data from server but while assign to json getting that above error. Can you please help me where I am doing mistake.

**My response Json:**

```
[{"id":485,"orderno":"00605164","type":"typeA","description":"description"},{"id":486,"orderno":"00605164","type":"typeB","description":"description"}]
```

Comment: if the JSON what you posted in your questions is the final output, then it's already in JSON format. There is no need to convert it again.

Comment: the dojo2 `.json()` method is asynchronous pulling the data from the response and returns a promise to the converted JS object !

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a serverside issue and not dojo related.

I reproduced your example with a sample json :

```
const json = request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
            .then(response => response.json());
```

and the data is fine.

Here is the complete example

```
import request from '@dojo/core/request';
import xhr from '@dojo/core/request/providers/xhr';

request.setDefaultProvider(xhr);
const json = request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Although the `xhr` is optional (it is the default, I guess) - this is fine in a browser and if you replace `xhr` by `node` it works fine in Node.js too.

How is your Server transferring the JSON - maybe as html ?
Also: What exactly is your dojo version?

More information for request than on https://dojo.io can be found in
https://github.com/dojo/core/tree/master/src/request

Answer (score -1):

You got an array as response, try to use
    response[0].json()

Comment: An array IS a valid JSON in a string response.